# WiFi fails with 18.04.2 upgrade on Asus E200HA

Tags: wireless, upgrade

Yesterday my laptop ([ASUS E200HA](https://www.asus.com/us/Laptops/ASUS-Vivobook-E200HA/specifications/)) was upgraded to 18.04.2, but now the WiFi doesn't work.  I've tried following just about every instruction for 10 hours now and still no joy.  Bluetooth works, which is how I'm connected just now.

```bsh
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

$ sudo lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2b31]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 31
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=ath10k_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:126 memory:91200000-913fffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       logical name: bnep0
       serial: f0:03:8c:a2:28:58
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes ip=172.20.10.5 multicast=yes

$ sudo lspci -v
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter (rev 31)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 127
    Memory at 91200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=2M]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/8 Maskable+ 64bit-
    Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [148] Virtual Channel
    Capabilities: [168] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
    Capabilities: [178] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [180] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath10k_pci
```

```bsh
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 28 May 2019 23:33 BST +0100

Booted last: 28 May 2019 00:00 BST +0100

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 4.16.0+ #1 SMP Mon Apr 2 16:37:34 CEST 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0042] (rev 31)
    Subsystem: AzureWave QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2b31]
    Kernel driver in use: ath10k_pci

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 13d3:3496 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:57ed Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot disabled
Platform is in Setup Mode

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            28672  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
ath10k_pci             49152  0
ath10k_core           368640  1 ath10k_pci
ath                    28672  1 ath10k_core
mac80211              778240  1 ath10k_core
cfg80211              626688  3 mac80211,ath,ath10k_core
wmi                    24576  1 asus_wmi
video                  40960  3 asus_wmi,int3406_thermal,i915

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: bnep0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'bnep0' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.20.10.5/28 brd 172.20.10.15 scope global dynamic noprefixroute bnep0
       valid_lft 78767sec preferred_lft 78767sec
    inet6 fe80::9fdd:81cf:7b9c:d633/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

bnep0     no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 172.20.10.1 dev bnep0 proto dhcp metric 750 
169.254.0.0/16 dev bnep0 scope link metric 1000 
172.20.10.0/28 dev bnep0 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.10.5 metric 750 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       792     1  0 21:39 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_80_82_23_4F_5C_C2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       bnep0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Ian’s iPhone Network
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       249c8e9b-a032-476d-a939-857f8c8e49b0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.20.10.5/28
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.20.10.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.20.10.1, mt = 750
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 172.20.10.0/28, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 750
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        server_name = Ians-iPhone
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        next_server = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       broadcast_address = 172.20.10.15
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 85536
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       routers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 172.20.10.5
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.240
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       expiry = 1559161556
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       domain_name_servers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       network_number = 172.20.10.0
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 172.20.10.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9fdd:81cf:7b9c:d633/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 750
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{15}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   249c8e9b-a032-476d-a939-857f8c8e49b0 | Ian’s iPhone Network

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bt
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceBt
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         --
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        --
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         bluez
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC address>
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          30 (disconnected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /org/bluez/hci0/dev_78_C3_E9_83_F1_DD
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            no
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
BLUETOOTH.CAPABILITIES:                 NAP
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{14}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   f3267832-b90a-4cbf-bd86-86d4c9a1929b | Galaxy J5 Network

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/HolidayInnGuestWi-Fi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=HolidayInnGuestWi-Fi | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=HolidayInnGuestWi-Fi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Ian’s iPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Ian’s iPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=73;97;110;226;128;153;115;32;105;80;104;111;110;101;
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ZyXELEA57DC]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ZyXELEA57DC | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ZyXELEA57DC
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/SWR WiFi]] (600 root)
[connection] id=SWR WiFi | type=wifi | autoconnect=false | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=SWR WiFi
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Private Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Private Guest | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Private Guest
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ZyXELEA57DC_5G]] (600 root)
[connection] id=ZyXELEA57DC_5G | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=ZyXELEA57DC_5G
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/iPhone]] (600 root)
[connection] id=iPhone | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=iPhone
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/77X_Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=77X_Guest | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=77X_Guest
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/DIO-WIFI]] (600 root)
[connection] id=DIO-WIFI | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=DIO-WIFI
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/RSMS_Guest]] (600 root)
[connection] id=RSMS_Guest | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=RSMS_Guest
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/PlusnetWireless2B7338]] (600 root)
[connection] id=PlusnetWireless2B7338 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=PlusnetWireless2B7338
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

[[/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Sagemcom-QR6Q78]] (600 root)
[connection] id=Sagemcom-QR6Q78 | type=wifi | permissions=
[wifi] mac-address=<MAC address> | mac-address-blacklist= | ssid=Sagemcom-QR6Q78
[ipv4] method=auto
[ipv6] method=auto

##### Netplan config ####################

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/London (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

bnep0     no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

bnep0     Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[ath10k_pci]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.0+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_pci.ko
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9377/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-6.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA6174/hw2.1/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA9887/hw1.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board-2.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/board.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-5.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-4.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-3.bin
firmware:       ath10k/QCA988X/hw2.0/firmware-2.bin
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Driver support for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac WLAN PCIe/AHB devices
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     228292A42E3072B9E09755C
depends:        ath10k_core
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_pci
vermagic:       4.16.0+ SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           irq_mode:0: auto, 1: legacy, 2: msi (default: 0) (uint)
parm:           reset_mode:0: auto, 1: warm only (default: 0) (uint)

[ath10k_core]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.0+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath10k/ath10k_core.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Core module for Qualcomm Atheros 802.11ac wireless LAN cards.
author:         Qualcomm Atheros
srcversion:     D96CC39234307CA4276A7C8
depends:        mac80211,cfg80211,ath
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath10k_core
vermagic:       4.16.0+ SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           debug_mask:Debugging mask (uint)
parm:           uart_print:Uart target debugging (bool)
parm:           skip_otp:Skip otp failure for calibration in testmode (bool)
parm:           cryptmode:Crypto mode: 0-hardware, 1-software (uint)
parm:           rawmode:Use raw 802.11 frame datapath (bool)
parm:           coredump_mask:Bitfield of what to include in firmware crash file (ulong)

[ath]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.0+/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/ath/ath.ko
license:        Dual BSD/GPL
description:    Shared library for Atheros wireless LAN cards.
author:         Atheros Communications
srcversion:     555BBBB9D4FCA58A05E7C0D
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           ath
vermagic:       4.16.0+ SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4

[mac80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.0+/kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko
license:        GPL
description:    IEEE 802.11 subsystem
srcversion:     8FA1436C1506A22E399CDBE
depends:        cfg80211
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           mac80211
vermagic:       4.16.0+ SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           minstrel_vht_only:Use only VHT rates when VHT is supported by sta. (bool)
parm:           max_nullfunc_tries:Maximum nullfunc tx tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           max_probe_tries:Maximum probe tries before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           beacon_loss_count:Number of beacon intervals before we decide beacon was lost. (int)
parm:           probe_wait_ms:Maximum time(ms) to wait for probe response before disconnecting (reason 4). (int)
parm:           ieee80211_default_rc_algo:Default rate control algorithm for mac80211 to use (charp)

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/4.16.0+/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
author:         Johannes Berg
srcversion:     2443BFD11787A6D4458157B
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       4.16.0+ SMP mod_unload 
signat:         PKCS#7
signer:         
sig_key:        
sig_hashalgo:   md4
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[ath10k_pci]
irq_mode: 0
reset_mode: 0

[ath10k_core]
coredump_mask: 3
cryptmode: 0
debug_mask: 0
rawmode: N
skip_otp: N
uart_print: N

[mac80211]
beacon_loss_count: 7
ieee80211_default_rc_algo: minstrel_ht
max_nullfunc_tries: 2
max_probe_tries: 5
minstrel_vht_only: Y
probe_wait_ms: 500

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723de.conf]
options rtl8723de ant_sel=X

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos and edit your post to include wireless script results

Comment: Thanks, have done that (see above).

Comment: Another whole day trying to resolve this - is there another update coming out to correct the last update?  I'm so fed up with this I'm on the verge of going back to Mint :(

Comment: try `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/*` and reboot, wifi power management might be causing the driver to crash

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy31 tried that but sadly no joy.  Still no wifi adapter found.

Comment: SOLVED!  I found a file called firmware-6.bin in the hw1.0 folder.  I deleted this, leaving firmware-5.bin, and rebooted.  Now working fine.

Comment: Strange as the wireless script results didn't show any sign of a firmware crash

Answer (score 2):

<sup>Copied from OP's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1146954/wifi-fails-with-18-04-2-upgrade#comment1905680_1146954):</sup>

> SOLVED! I found a file called `firmware-6.bin` in the `hw1.0` folder. I deleted this, leaving `firmware-5.bin`, and rebooted. Now working fine.